# Anaconda zsh pip list different from bash pip list Mac OS High Sierra

Tags: python, anaconda, zsh

I installed Anaconda a while ago and I'm very new to Python.. but I can't seem to figure this out.

After the installation, everything seems to work okay, `conda` is a valid command however, when I do `pip list` in zsh and `pip list` in bash I get returned two very different lists. Bash displays everything that Anaconda came pre-packaged with and zsh does not, is there a way to get zsh to see all of those packages?

**I use zsh instead not bash**

Thanks!

Comment: You need to modify your zshrc to adjust your PATHs

Comment: Try `python -m pip list ` in your zsh.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the PATH environment variable has a different default value  in zsh and bash. Modifiy PATH as follows:

1. open zsh and create a file named ".zshrc" in home dir.
2. add `export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH` to .zshrc and save it
3. load the new configuration by executing `source .zshrc` in zsh.

(zsh) PATH is now equivalent to (bash) PATH and pip should return the same list in both shells.